# T-SQL how to join with one column a string and one an integer

Tags: t-sql

How to join with one column a string and one an integer?
--PEOPLE_ID 000092437, PersonID 92437

```
select PC.PEOPLE_ID, Idn.PersonId,'Home Row 1', PC.Phone1 from @NextIdentityID Idn INNER JOIN PEOPLECHANGES PC on Idn.People_ID = PC.People_ID --PEOPLE_ID 000092437, PersonID 92437 one is varchar, one is integer
union all select PC.PEOPLE_ID, Idn.PersonId,'Office Row 2', PC.Phone2 from @NextIdentityID Idn INNER JOIN PEOPLECHANGES PC on Idn.People_ID = PC.People_ID
union all select PC.PEOPLE_ID, Idn.PersonId,'Cell Row 3', PC.Phone3 from @NextIdentityID Idn INNER JOIN PEOPLECHANGES PC on Idn.People_ID = PC.People_ID
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/conversion-functions-transact-sql

Comment: Aside: The performance may vary considerably depending on which direction you choose to convert, i.e `VarChar` to `Int` or vice versa. It depends on whether there are indexes, the index statistics, ... . It might be worth adding an indexed computed column to improve performance. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. I've assumed SQL Server of some recent vintage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure your varchar() data doesn't raise any errors you should check to see if it can be converted into an integer. One way to do this is with a case statement in the where clause.  If it is not convertible then your join won't work - but at least your query can still run with out error.

This example shows how you can avoid potential errors.

```
create table #tempa(id int, descr varchar(50));
create table #tempb(id varchar(10), descr varchar(50));

insert into #tempa(id,descr) values (1234,'Body getta body getta');
insert into #tempb(id,descr) values ('001234','sis boom ba - rah rah rah');
insert into #tempa(id,descr) values (5678,'Weagle Weagle War Damn Eagle');
insert into #tempb(id,descr) values ('0005678','Kickem in the butt Big blue');
insert into #tempa(id,descr) values (9012,'this wont have a match');
insert into #tempb(id,descr) values ('x0912','sis boom ba');

Select a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id
,a.descr as a_descr, b.descr as b_descr
from #tempa a
left join #tempb b
on a.id = case when isnumeric(b.id) = 1 then cast(b.id as int) else 0 end

-- this one will raise an error
Select a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id
,a.descr as a_descr, b.descr as b_descr
from #tempa a
left join #tempb b
on a.id = b.id


drop table #tempa;
drop table #tempb;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the one with leading zeros to an integer you will get equal values:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '000092437') = 92437
```

However, this assumes that all of your varchar column can be convert to int.

If that's not the case then you have to write a function to go the other way and add leading zeros.